# How to convert this sample foreach into lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, generics

How to convert this sample foreach into lambda expression?

```
 foreach (ADOMD.Member iMember in pMemberCollection)
                    {
                        decimal lDimensionValue = 0;
                        if (Decimal.TryParse(iMember.Name, out lDimensionValue))
                            lDimensionValues.Add(lDimensionValue);                     
                    }
                   lDimensionValues.Sort();
```

ADOMD.Member is a interface looks like

```
[TypeLibType(xxx)]
[Guid("xxxxx")]
public interface Member
{
    [DispId(0)]
    string Caption { get; }
    [DispId(1610743817)]
    int ChildCount { get; }         
    string Name { get; }
    [DispId(1610743812)]
    Member Parent { get; }
    [DispId(1610743819)]
    bool ParentSameAsPrev { get; }
    [DispId(1610743815)]
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your foreach will most likely be faster than the equivalent lambda.

Comment: Since each loop in the for each is independent I would suggest using a parallel for loop and dumping the values in a concurrent collection and then sort at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
lDimensionValues =
 pMemberCollection
 .Cast<ADOMD.Member>()
 .Select(iMember => {
    decimal lDimensionValue = 0;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(iMember.Name, out lDimensionValue))
        return (decimal?)lDimensionValue;
    else return null;
  })
.Where(x => x != null)
.Select(x => x.Value)
.OrderBy(x => x)
.ToList();
```

Very ugly and verbose. If we had a `TryParseDecimal` method it would be cleaner.

This is not a perfect case for LINQ. Among other reasons due to the legacy collection that requires a `Cast` apparently.

Comment: If only there was some kind of C# equivalent to F#'s `Seq.choose`, that would make this an order of magnitude prettier.

Comment: @TheInnerLight good point, in particular combined with a possible TryParseDecimal (which is a good util method to have around). I'll implement a Choose extension method right now, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Had to try to do this in as few lines as possible, interesting problem, i would not convert your method to LINQ though, if it already works (what works works)

```
lDimensionValues = pMemberCollection.Where(a => {
           decimal lDimensionValued;
           return decimal.TryParse(a.Name, out lDimensionValued);
       }).Select(a=> decimal.Parse(a.Name)).Sort();
```